# Checking database if There is Match Found Using Select WHERE Query Access

Tags: vba

Guys i'm using select where query using vb access code, i have no problem with checking if records match, i'm having problems with if sTextbox does not match the value in the data base... it should print "No Record Match" only once, but in this statement it prints out MsgBox("No Record Match") the numerous times until the Record in database has been all compared... i can't add Exit Do, cause it will only run the statement once and it will not compare the sTextbox to all the values of the database... i'm  not allowed to use any other means except with sql query statement. I would really appreciate the help Thank You very much.

```
Dim MyDB As DAO.Database, MyRec As DAO.Recordset, MyList As String
Dim fQue As String, lQue As String, tQue As String

Set MyDB = CurrentDb

If IsNull(sTextbox) Or sTextbox = "" Then
     MsgBox ("You must enter Value in Search Box")
End If

If (sTextbox <> "") Or (sTextbox <> "") Then
MsgBox ("There is value")


Set MyDB = CurrentDb
Set MyRec = MyDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * From clientInfo")


Do While Not MyRec.EOF 'Loop to check if sTextbox = tQue
  fQue = MyRec![FirstName]
  lQue = MyRec![LastName]
  tQue = MyRec![towerUnit]
  MyRec.MoveNext

    If (sTextbox = tQue) Then
       Set MyDB = CurrentDb
       Set MyRec = MyDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * From clientInfo where TowerUnit='" & sTextbox & "'")

       FullName = lQue & ", " & fQue
       MsgBox (FullName)
       ClientTextbox.Value = lQue & ", " & fQue
        UnitTextbox.Value = tQue
        Exit Do
    End If

    If (sTextbox <> tQue) Then

        MsgBox ("No Record Found")
        ''Problem lies here because it prints out MsgBox until the While loop is false...
    End If

Loop
```

End If

Comment: Why are you making the first query with no "where" clause? You only need to make a single query using the textbox value: if it's EOF then there are no matching records...

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim recordNotFound as Boolean = False
<Your While Loop>  
 ...

  If (sTextbox <> tQue) Then
        recordNotFound = True
        ''Or you can do something more complicated like recordNotFound = recordNotFound Or True depending on what you are trying to accomplish
        ''Problem lies here because it prints out MsgBox until the While loop is false...
    End If
 ...
<End Of your While Loop>

if recordNotFound Then MsgBox ("No Record Found")
```

Comment: hmm I would probably restructure it to `if (stextbox = tQue) Then <br> recordFound = True <br> Exit Do <br> End if` Or just make the SQL do the work for me. If you don't then if there's a match on the first record but not on the second you'll get the MsgBox

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim MyDB As DAO.Database, MyRec As DAO.Recordset
Dim fQue As String, lQue As String, tQue As String

Set MyDB = CurrentDb

If Len(sTextbox)=0 Then
    MsgBox ("You must enter Value in Search Box")
    Exit Sub
End If

Set MyDB = CurrentDb

Set MyRec = MyDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * From clientInfo where TowerUnit='" _
                                & sTextbox & "'")

If Not MyRec.EOF Then

    fQue = MyRec![FirstName]
    lQue = MyRec![LastName]
    tQue = MyRec![towerUnit]

    ClientTextbox.Value = lQue & ", " & fQue
    UnitTextbox.Value = tQue

Else

    MsgBox ("No Record Found")

End If
```